# Want to keep video display off on my HTC1X

Tags: screen

While playing videos on my HDTV big screen through my cell phone HTC1X using MHL-HDMI adapter, I want to keep display off on my cell to conserve battery and avoid cell getting heated up as it is happening now. I set the brightness to minimum level but it helped only marginally. Can any one suggest a way out please. Regards,
Colonel Narender Singh

Comment: I think that depends on you video player app. MXPlayer has a background play toggle in settings that permits screen powering off without stopping playback.

Answer (score 0):

As explained above, though I have a Chromecast but some how ES File Explorer through which I used to view my stored videos, used to take about 15-20 minutes to recognise Chromecast in LAN which was very irritating. So I went for HDMI cable and MHL to HDMI Adapter. Though it started working fine but the problem was that the cell phone used to get heated up very soon and battery consumption was much on the higher side. I was not very comfortable with the situation. Though I found an application 'Allcast' which sorted out the problem of heating up to a great extent by switching off the screen while playing the video in the background, but still the heating up problem was there though only 50% now. So I thought of trying 'Allcast' with Chromecast and it immediately recognised it and now there was no problem at all playing all my stored videos. The display also could be put off and video continued to run in the background. No heating up of phone at all was noticed and battery consumption was also minimum. Happy situation. I removed HDMI cable and the adopter with its charger as nothing was required now. One more thing happened which I don't know how, ever since I switched over from ES File Explorer to 'Allcast' app in Chromecast, even ES File Explorer suddenly started behaving now and for the last 2-3 days, it is recognising my Chromecast instantly without any delay. Had this happened before, I would have saved about INR 2700/- on purchase of good quality HDMI cable, Adapter and Sony charger of 2.1 amp. But still very happy and satisfied now with the performance of Chromecast through either of the two applications 'ES File Explorer' or 'Allcast'. Nothing can beat Chromecast. It is superb. Any one wants to play stored as well as live videos, go for Chromecast and don't get involved with cables and Adapter.  I thought of sharing my experience with you all. Thanks for the patience of reading my thesis. Regards. Col. Narender